# stop load items in pagination if items is refreshing

Tags: flutter, dart

The main idea is downloading new item should not start if an update is currently in progress. So I created this code, and as I think, it should stop to load the new items if the refreshing is still processing.

```
void _onScroll() {
    const isRefresh = true;
    if (scrollController.position.pixels >=
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      if (isRefresh) {
        _currentPlaceState.content([]);
      }
      _loadPlaces();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform what you want first thing make sure you take `const isRefresh = true;` out of the `_onScroll` function I personally use the upcoming flow

```
bool isRefresh = false;
_onscroll(){
  if(isRefresh){
     return;
  }
  isRefresh = true;
  _loadPlaces().then(
  (res){
      isRefresh = false;
  });
  
}
```